# Can't Access Cordova plugin in Second page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to include Camera plugin into my cordova app build for ios. so i used a sample from internet
this is my code and its working

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var pictureSource;
    var destinationType; 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    function capturePhoto() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }
    function getPhoto(source) {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onClick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onClick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onClick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

But i have a lot of pages in my app. so i created more html pages . and give a href link to this page. 
I called this page url from another page but it didnt work out. i have added these cordova.js and script files into my index.html page. still i cant access camera. 
how could i solve this problem?? how can i access those plugins in page other than starting page???

guys please help me.. :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `deviceready` event fires only once when the application starts. You can safely access the `navigator.camera` without waiting for the event on your next pages. In fact your code will fail because `pictureSource` and `destinationType` will be undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var pictureSource = pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType; 

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

function capturePhoto() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

function capturePhotoEdit() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
function getPhoto(source) {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
</script>
```

If you're testing the application on an Android phone ADT bundle provides `logcat` for tracing JavaScript errors on the device.

Comment: i did these change but code stilll does'nt work.. :(  
[INFO:CONSOLE(112)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (112)

here is the new error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your camera cordova plugin file js with this one

```
var pictureSource;
var destinationType;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = imageData;
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
    });
}

function capturePhotoEdit() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 20,
        allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
    });
}

function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source
    });
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```